# How to pass a canvas to another class Python?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I want to pass my canvas I made in one class into another. I have tried using inheritance but it still doesn't work.

I also tried using a get and set method to get the circuitCanvas from the programGUI class but it still doesn't work. I found the 'getattr' to get the canvas using fullstops here but I can't get it to work either. Any suggestions?

This is the code I have so far with the get/set method:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

gate_id=0
input_id=0
output_id=0

class titleLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self,master,**config):
        super(titleLabel,self).__init__(master,**config)
        self.config(bg="LIGHTGREY")
        self.config(width=33)
        self.config(font=("Courier",30))
        self.config(anchor=CENTER)

class buttonLayout(Button):
    def __init__(self,master,**config):
        super(buttonLayout,self).__init__(master,**config)
        self.config(font=("Courier",12))
        self.config(bg="LIGHTGREY")


class programGUI(Frame): 
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(programGUI,self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.menuFrame = Frame(self)
        self.circuitFrame = Frame(self)
        self.circuitCanvas = Canvas(self.circuitFrame,height=800,width=900,bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        self.create_menu_widgets()
        self.create_circuit_widgets(self.circuitCanvas)
        self.menuFrame.grid()
        Circuit(self.circuitFrame)

    def create_menu_widgets(self):
        lblWelcome=titleLabel(self.menuFrame,text="LOGIC GATE CIRCUIT PROGRAM")
        lblWelcome.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=12,padx=50)
        lblTitle = Label(self.menuFrame,text="Main Menu",font="Courier",width=60)
        lbl1=Label(self.menuFrame,width=60,bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        lbl1.grid(row=5,column=0)
        btnCircuit = buttonLayout(self.menuFrame,text="Create Circuit",command=lambda:self.goToCircuitScreen())
        lbl2=Label(self.menuFrame,width=60,bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        lbl2.grid(row=7,column=0)
        btnExit = buttonLayout(self.menuFrame,text="Exit",command=lambda:self.quitProgram())
        lbl4=Label(self.menuFrame,width=60,bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        lbl4.grid(row=11,column=0)
        lblTitle.grid(row=4,column=0,pady=12,padx=50)
        btnCircuit.grid(row=6,column=0)
        btnExit.grid(row=14,column=0)
        lbl5=Label(self.menuFrame,width=60,bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        lbl5.grid(row=13,column=0)
        lbl6=Label(self.menuFrame,width=60,bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        lbl6.grid(row=15,column=0)
        lbl7=Label(self.menuFrame,width=60,bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        lbl7.grid(row=16,column=0)
        circuitPic=PhotoImage(file="circuit1.gif")
        circuitPicLabel=Label(self.menuFrame,image=circuitPic)
        circuitPicLabel.photo=circuitPic
        circuitPicLabel.grid(row=16,column=0,padx=50)
        self.menuFrame.config(bg="LIGHTBLUE")
        lblTitle.config(bg="white",fg="BLACK")


    def create_circuit_widgets(self,circuitCanvas):
        lblWelcome=titleLabel(self.circuitFrame,text="LOGIC GATE CIRCUIT")
        lblWelcome.place(x=50,y=25)
        backButton = buttonLayout(self.circuitFrame,text="BACK",command=lambda:self.goToMenu())
        backButton.place(x=775,y=650)
        self.circuitCanvas.grid()


        def addOutput():
            global output_id
            output_id+=1
            output_tag="output-%s"%output_id
            tags=("output",output_tag)
            self.circuitCanvas.create_rectangle(200,200,225,225,width=5,fill="WHITE",tag=tags) 
            self.circuitCanvas.tag_bind(output_tag, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, tag=output_tag: moveInOutput(event, tag))


        def addInput():
            global input_id
            input_id+=1
            input_tag="input-%s"%input_id
            tags=("input",input_tag)
            print(tags)
            self.circuitCanvas.create_oval(200,200,225,225,fill="WHITE",width=5,tag=tags)
            self.circuitCanvas.tag_bind(input_tag, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, tag=input_tag: moveInOutput(event, tag))


        def moveInOutput(event, tag):
            x=event.x
            y=event.y
            coords=self.circuitCanvas.coords(tag)
            movex=x-coords[0]
            movey=y-coords[1]
            self.circuitCanvas.move(tag, movex, movey)
            for item in self.circuitCanvas.find_all():
               tags = self.circuitCanvas.gettags(item)
               if tag in tags:
                   if 'input' in tags:
                       #current item is an input of the moved object
                       #Get the items coordinates
                       coords = self.circuitCanvas.coords(item)
                       #Find if we overlap with other objects
                       closest = self.circuitCanvas.find_overlapping(coords[0]-5,coords[1]-5,coords[2]+5,coords[3]+5)
                       for closest_item in closest:
                           closest_tags = self.circuitCanvas.gettags(closest_item)
                           if 'output' in closest_tags:
                               #If we overlap with another object, print connected and the appropriate tags
                               print("connected", closest_tags, "-", tag)
                               connected_coords = self.circuitCanvas.coords(closest_item)
                               snapx = coords[0] - connected_coords[0]
                               snapy = coords[1] - connected_coords[1]
                               self.circuitCanvas.move(tag, -snapx, -snapy)


        self.circuitCanvas.create_rectangle(120,130,760,600,fill="WHITE",width=5)
            addInputBtn=buttonLayout(self.circuitFrame,text="Input",command=lambda:addInput())
        addInputBtn.place(x=25,y=200)
        addOutputBtn=buttonLayout(self.circuitFrame,text="Output",command=lambda:addOutput())
        addOutputBtn.place(x=20,y=400)


    def goToCircuitScreen(self):
        self.menuFrame.grid_remove()
        self.circuitFrame.grid()


    def goToMenu(self):
        self.circuitFrame.grid_remove()
        self.menuFrame.grid()

    def quitProgram(self):
        exit()

class Circuit(programGUI):

    def __init__(self,circuitFrame):
        super(programGUI,self).__init__(circuitFrame)
        self.runBtn=buttonLayout(circuitFrame,activebackground="green",text="Run",command=lambda:validationCircuit(self))
        self.runBtn.place(x=250,y=630)
        self.var = StringVar(circuitFrame)
        self.var.set('NOT')
        self.choices = ['NOT','AND','OR','NAND','XOR','NOR','|','--']
        self.option = OptionMenu(circuitFrame, self.var, *self.choices)
        self.option.place(x=790,y=200)
        self.addNodeBtn = buttonLayout(circuitFrame, text="Add Node", command=lambda:self.gateSelected())
        self.addNodeBtn.place(x=780,y=400)
        self.clearButton = buttonLayout(circuitFrame,text="Clear",command=lambda:self.clearScreen())
        self.clearButton.place(x=420,y=630)
        self.orGATE()
        self.norGATE()
        self.moveGate()
        self.getCanvas(programGUI)
        self.setCanvas(programGUI)


    def getCanvas(self,programGUI):
        getattr(programGUI,"self.circuitCanvas")
        return self.circuitCanvas()

    def setCanvas(self,circuitCanvas):
        setattr(Circuit,"self.circuitCanvas")


    def gateSelected(self):
        sf = self.var.get()
        if sf=='OR':
            self.orGATE()       
        elif sf=='NOR':
            self.norGATE()


    def validationCircuit(self):
        empty(gate_id)
        validGates(gate_id)
        validInOutputs(outputNum,inputNum)

    def clearScreen(self):
        global gate_id
        circuitCanvas=self.circuitFrame
        self.circuitCanvas.delete("orgate","norgate","output","input")
        gate_id=0
        outputNum=0
        inputNum=0
        return outputNum,inputNum


    def norGATE(self):
        global gate_id
        gate_id+=1
        gate_tag="norgate-%s"%gate_id
        tags=("norgate",gate_tag)
        inputs = ("norgate", gate_tag, "input")
        outputs = ("norgate", gate_tag, "output")
        self.circuitCanvas.create_oval(240,217,255,232,fill="black",tag=tags)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_polygon(200,200,250,225,200,250,210,225,width=5,tag=tags)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(245,225,280,225,width=5,tag=tags)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(210,213,173,213,width=5,tag=tags)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(210,238,173,238,width=5,tag=tags)
        #End of output
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(280,225,285,225, width=5, fill="red", tags=outputs)
        #End of inputs
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(173,213,168,213, width=5, fill="blue", tags=inputs)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(173,238,168,238, width=5, fill="blue", tags=inputs)        
        self.circuitCanvas.tag_bind(gate_tag, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, tag=gate_tag: moveGate(event, tag))


    def orGATE(self):
        global gate_id
        gate_id+=1
        gate_tag="orgate-%s"%gate_id
        tags=("orgate",gate_tag)
        inputs = ("orgate", gate_tag, "input")
        outputs = ("orgate", gate_tag, "output")
        self.circuitCanvas.create_polygon(200,200,250,225,200,250,210,225,width=5,tag=tags)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(245,225,280,225,width=5,tag=tags)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(210,213,173,213,width=5,tag=tags)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(210,238,173,238,width=5,tag=tags)
        #End of output
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(280,225,285,225, width=5, fill="red", tags=outputs)
        #End of inputs
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(173,213,168,213, width=5, fill="blue", tags=inputs)
        self.circuitCanvas.create_line(173,238,168,238, width=5, fill="blue", tags=inputs)
        self.circuitCanvas.tag_bind(gate_tag, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, tag=gate_tag: moveGate(event, tag))

    def moveGate(self,event,tag):
        x=event.x
        y=event.y
        coords=self.circuitCanvas.coords(tag)
        movex=x-coords[0]
        movey=y-coords[1]
        self.circuitCanvas.move(tag, movex, movey)
        for item in self.circuitCanvas.find_all():
         tags = self.circuitCanvas.gettags(item)
         if tag in tags:
             if 'input' in tags:
                 #current item is an input of the moved object
                 #Get the items coordinates
                 coords = self.circuitCanvas.coords(item)
                 #Find if we overlap with other objects
                 closest = self.circuitCanvas.find_overlapping(coords[0]-5,coords[1]-5,coords[2]+5,coords[3]+5)
                 for closest_item in closest:
                     closest_tags = self.circuitCanvas.gettags(closest_item)
                     if 'output' in closest_tags:
                         #If we overlap with another object, print connected and the appropriate tags
                         print("connected", closest_tags, "-", tag)
                         connected_coords = self.circuitCanvas.coords(closest_item)
                         snapx = coords[0] - connected_coords[0]
                         snapy = coords[1] - connected_coords[1]
                         self.circuitCanvas.move(tag, -snapx, -snapy)



root = Tk()
root.title("Logic Gate Circuit Program")
root.geometry("900x695")
myGUI = programGUI(root)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `circuitCanvas` canvas is a mere attribute of your `programGUI` class's instances.
It so happens that, by inheritance, and because you're initializing them with `super`, a `Circuit` instance also is an instance of `programGUI`.

As a result, an instance of `Circuit` already has a `circuitCanvas` attribute, so inside of it, you can just write `self.circuitCanvas`.

---

Now a word on your `getCanvas` and `setCanvas` methods (which you don't need, per the above answer, but they still need remarks).

You define `getCanvas` as follows:

```
def getCanvas(self,programGUI):
    getattr(programGUI,"self.circuitCanvas")
    return self.circuitCanvas()
```

First, the call to `getattr` is useless, because you don't do anything with its return value (well, excluding all side effects, but hopefully there aren't).
But anyway, the second argument is the name of the attribute you're looking for, so it should simply be `circuitCanvas`.

The return statement is a bit perplexing.
Your goal is to get the `circuitCanvas` member, so why even bother writing a method?
If you can get `self.circuitCanvas` in your function, then you can outside too.
Besides, you're calling `circuitCanvas`, by writing `self.circuitCanvas()`.
Hopefully, `circuitCanvas` is an instance of `tkinter.Canvas`, which is not callable.
So it's just gonna crash.

`setCanvas` is just weird.
There's a parameter which isn't event used, you use `setattr` on the `Circuit` class, which only adds an attribute to the class itself...
You're just overcomplicating the thing.
As written above, your `Circuit` class extends `programGUI`, so its instances **do** have that `circuitCanvas` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when I put self.circuitCanvas in the class it still doesn't work. @right-leg